# Fold, Gather, Cut

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a mathematical puzzle I've been thinking about.  Let's say you have a strip of fabric, of length $N$ units ($N$ being an integer), which has regular markings on it every 1 unit along its length.  Your task is to cut the fabric into $N$ lengths of 1 unit each, but to do so using the fewest operations possible.  The operations available to you are:

1. Cut - you may cut through any number of overlapping layers in a single operation.  All cuts must be through the 1-unit markings on the fabric, and the cut must be in a straight line.  (No using a wavy cut to do the whole thing in 1 operation.)
2. Gather - you may gather any number of already-cut lengths together in a bundle.  They must all line up on one end.  (If they are the same lengths, they will of course line up on both ends.)
3. Fold - You may fold any number of layers of fabric in either direction.  Multiple folds can only be counted as 1 operation if the places to be folded are already lined up, either via a previous Gather or another Fold step.  Unlike Cuts, a Fold may occur between the 1-unit markings.  Unfolding does not require an additional operation.

Now it can be trivially shown that for any $N$ which is $2^k$, an ideal solution would be to have $k$ Cuts alternating with $k-1$ Gathers, for a total of $2k - 1$ operations.  This is by no means the only ideal solution.  For example, consider $N=8$.  The steps could be:

1. Cut into 2 lengths of 4.
2. Gather lengths.
3. Cut into 4 lengths of 2.
4. Gather lengths.
5. Cut into 8 lengths of 1.

Or you could do the following:

1. Fold at the 3rd marking.
2. Fold at the 5th marking the other direction.
3. Cut down the middle to get 4 lengths of 2 (2 of which are folded).
4. Gather lengths.
5. Cut into 8 lengths of 1.

Still 5 steps either way.  It gets trickier when you consider other numbers however.  Say, for $N=9$, you could take any $N=8$ solution, and then add 1 more cut for that last piece that will be 1 unit too long.  But you can do 9 in 5 steps as well:

1. Fold in half.
2. Cut at the 3rd and 6th markings (which should be lined up) to get 3 lengths of 3.
3. Gather lengths.
4. Fold all 3 in half again.
5. Cut into 9 lengths of 1.

So my question is, with the given operations, can you compute the minimum number of operations for any given $N$?

Comment: You shouldn't cut multiple layers of fabric like this - it'll ruin your shears.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I use a high-powered imaginary laser when cutting mathematically arbitrary layers of fabric.  Folding also gets tough when you have a lot of layers, but we're not taking that into account here.

Comment: Can you explain how you argue that $2^k$ needs at least $2k-1$ operations?

Comment: @Vadim123 I believe that counts as $2N-4$ folds, because they are not already lined up.

Comment: @CalvinLin: If you ignore the Fold operation, you can simply cut it in half and gather until you're done.  However, that may be wrong, since folds can double up, so I think Vadim123 below may be closer - though I think that's still not quite right.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman If you read Vadim's solution, we can do better than $2k-1$; in fact we get $k+2$ (yes these values agree for $k=3$. Hence, OP doesn't have an actual proof that "the ideal solution is $2k-1$ steps".

Comment: @CalvinLin Yeah, I'll concede that point.  I guess you can easily say that it's _no higher_ than $2k-1$, but $k+2$ is a closer bound.  Although, for $N=4$, you can do 3 steps - Cut, Gather, Cut, while $k+2$ would give you 4 steps in that case, so it's not quite right either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that does it in $2+\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$ steps.  This doesn't match the OP's algorithm for $n=9$, unfortunately, but it's "k+2" rather than "2k-1" when $n=2^k$.

1. Fold the fabric into a pile that is exactly 2 inches wide.  This takes $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil-1$ steps.
2. Cut down the middle.  This will leave many pieces of fabric, almost all 2 inches wide (perhaps one piece 1 inch wide).
3. Gather it all into a single pile, 2 inches wide.
4. Cut.

For example, if $n=16$.  Fold (8"), fold (4"), fold (2").  Cut, gather, cut.  6 steps.

Second example, if $17\le n\le 32$.  Pretend it's $32$, the next higher power of 2.  Fold (16"), fold (8"), fold (4"), fold (2").  Cut, gather, cut.  7 steps.

Comment: Actually, for odd numbers, you could leave one end dangling, so the folded stack is 2 wide except for at one end where it's 3.  Since you're cutting down the middle, that will still produce a length of 2, which can be gathered for the final cut.  For $N=9$ then, it'd still be 5 steps - Fold at the 4th mark, then fold again so it's 2 wide plus that dangling 3rd.  Cut, Gather, Cut again.  I believe this may be the best solution.

Comment: Then again, you could even leave 2 ends dangling the same way, so $N=10$ could also be 5 steps.  Fold in half, then Fold again for a stack 2 wide with 2 ends dangling.  Cut and you have 5 lengths of 2, which you can then Gather and Cut and be done.  Only at $N=11$ does it go up to 6 steps...

Comment: Taking the above into account, I'd say the actual formula would be $2+\lceil\log_2 (n-2)\rceil$.  That allows you to avoid some unnecessary folding steps for values within $2^k+2$.